# Trying to display a table with data from API, array inside JSON Object ANGULAR

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, typescript

I'm working in a project to help a friend, so most of the code in the services and the backend was already there, so I've been struggling with the structure and sometimes I get lost.

Here's my problem
This is the structure of the data on the API:

```
{
    "title": "",
    "iconURL": ",
    "linkedRightsIDs": [
        ""
    ],
    "linkedRights": [
        {
            "id": ,
            "creationDate": "",
            "sections": [
                "women"
            ],
            "defLanguage": "en",
            "countryApplied": "united states",
            "statesApplied": [
                "all"
            ],
            "title": "",
            "translations": [
                "en"
            ],
            "disable": false,
            "content": null
        }
    ]
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve, is to make a table inside my component using the LinkedRights data. Right now, this structure only have 1 linkedRight (I deleted the data inside for privacy)

Anyways, here's the method regarding the service and model in my component.ts:

```
  onModelLoadedAsync() {
    super.onModelLoadedAsync();

    if (this.mode == 'create') {
      this.model = LocalityInfo;
    } else {
      if (this.model.iconURL){
        this.imageSrc = this.model.iconURL;
      }
    }
    if(this.mode == 'edit'){

      const data= Object.entries(this.model.linkedRights); //this is me just testing
      console.log(data);
    }
  }
```

here's the html of the table I'm trying to display, this is and edit route so there's a query param for the id in this view

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table  class="table table-hover">
          <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Sections</th>
              <th>States</th>
              <th>Enabled</th>
              <th>Creation Date</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let item of data">
              <td>{{item.title}}</td>
              <td>{{item.sections}}</td>
              <td>{{item.statesApplied}}</td>
              <td>{{!item.disabled}}</td>
              <td>{{item.creationDate}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    
      </div>
    </div>
```

What I was trying to do, was to convert the JSON into an array so I could display it since there's an error that shows on the console that said this:

**core.js:6456 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.**

Comment: First, you haven't bound `data` to `this`, which means the template would have no access to the member. Second, each constituent of `Object.entries()` is an array tuple (i.e. `[key, value]`), so the attempts to directly access the properties won't work (e.g. `item.title`).

Comment: Can you try this for me?  let k = this.model.linkedRights;   let data= Object.keys(k).map(key => k[key]);
This should create an array from the object so that you can loop over it.

Comment: Hello to both of you, both answers where helpful. I realized that on my Object Model some names were incorrect and differed from the backend data. Also, I indeed needed to use model.LinkedRights to itterate with the NgFor.

Comment: Great, I hope it works for you now=)